# Using Freeform's Composer for CRUD operations?

Tags: craft3, plugin-freeform, solspace

I'm using **Freeform Pro**'s Composer to build front-end forms - seems to work great, including the association to an Element... creating entries from the form.

Is there any way to allow the author to do a little "Edit" of their entries? (such as sending an element type and ID to the function, so it loads that data in the form and allows us to save it?)

```
{{ craft.freeform.form("blogEntryForm").render() }}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Your question deserves a specific answer, but I thought it was worth noting that Craft lets you manage entries through front-end forms, out-of-the-box! As long as your permissions are set up properly, you can allow your users (logged in, or not) the ability to [interact directly with Entries](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html). You'd be responsible for displaying only a user's own entries, but the full suite of Entry actions are available to you just through the use of forms like this, paired with some smart queries, in your templates.

Comment: @AugustMiller - Thank you for that info - I'm familiar with that and have many entry forms on the front end of our site.  The ability to use Freeform's composer would liberate a significant amount of labor required in the development of front-end twig work to get everything connected and working.

Comment: FWIW, you _can_ generate forms dynamically via the Entry's `getFieldLayout()` method (the same way the CP does it)—but yeah, it'd be a non-zero amount of work to get the system set up, initially, especially when compared to the built-in FreeForm templates. Plus, you miss out on the advanced layout tools and page-splitting features! :(

Comment: hmm... the GetFieldLayout() might assist (still not as flexible as the layouts within freeform, but better than manually hard-coding each field on the form) - much appreciated, @AugustMiller